# Shading problem only when normal map is applied

Tags: shaders, normal-map

I have a very odd problem. My model looks perfectly fine with diffuse map on it and in Substance Painter too, but when I put my normal map on it it shows dark polys. The normals are in the right direction and I also tried to change the smoothing settings. But nothing worked. This never happened at my other models, only at the cars. (There are two more, where this issue is happening).

This dark patches also are shown in our own engine. I suspect there is something wrong with the tangent space, but I don't know much about this stuff. I tried to export it as FBX with Tangent Space checked on, but this doesn't helped either.

How you can see, the normal map is also fine. The place where the door sits is flat and shadeless blue.

Please can anybody help? This is very important for my work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add a pic with the normal map + your uv map on it ? that could help.

Comment: sure, here it is (see above)

Comment: I just noticed that the shading problem is on the mesh even when the normal map is off. But way more weaker. It is only visible in certain angles and lighting.

Comment: So you may share some screen captures of you material ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that if it is not directly or only due to the normal map, that can be or due to the material, or the mesh itself (but for the mesh you said you had checked the normals)

Comment: The material is the standard blender material with lesser hardness. Unsmooth shading occurs often at seams, but here it is only at the door and the front. I tried to cut the door out and make it to a new single object, but this didn't help either. It is still darker than the rest.

Comment: I think this is not due to the door, you can notice a difference also at the front and the back of the car (at the bottom). Is it the same if you render it ? Can you share your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: I am not allowed to give files away. I know that it isn't only at the door, it was an example. cause i think it is really strange that the problem doesn't disappear when the door becomes a new object. Especially cause the door is only a plane. I want to try another programm like max, maybe it is a blender issue.

And yes it is the same if i render it. In Blender render and in Cycles.